# Advantage over using spring-cache over Spring Data Repositories for Pivotal GemFire

Tags: caching, repository-pattern, gemfire, spring-cache, spring-data-gemfire

SDG (*Spring Data GemFire*) is a library or framework used by both Spring Cache (`GemfireCacheManager`) and Spring Data (`GemfireTemplate`) for `GemFire`.

Is there any noted deficiency/advantage in using one over the other?

The basic ***need*** of using the underlying data as a repo with `OQL` capabilities can be a differentiator and `GemfireTemplate` can provide `finder methods` which can serve as `cache lookup` and more like `search`, too.

On the other hand, `spring-cache` gives out-of-the-box capability for basic caching operations (get/put). If we want to do this using `GemfireTemplate` we have to write custom code.

Is there an ideal use case for `technically` using `spring-cache` for `GemFire` or vice-versa?

Answer (score 0):

Well, "caching" and "data access" patterns (CRUD + Querying, etc) are really 2 different concerns.

Caching is essentially, as the [Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache-strategies) explain, a way to reduce the costs of invoking an application service operation (a Java class "method" in Spring) when, given identical input, the same output or result is returned.

Costs can be measured many different ways but essentially boils down to CPU utilization, IO activity (e.g. disk/storage access), network (e.g. making a REST API call to a remote service, say like geocoding a address using Google's Maps API, [for instance](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/tree/master/caching-example/src/main/java/example/app)), etc.

By caching frequently or recently used results in memory, the application can be more responsive.  Of course, a developer must take care since s/he is trading performance (i.e. latency) at the expense of using more memory (i.e. resource utilization), so developers must be more selective about what is kept in memory, which is why caches typically use a LRU or LFU algorithm to maintain the most pertinent entries in the cache based on use.  That combined with other strategies (expiration (TTL or TTI), eviction, compression, using native memory, etc) can help.  In addition, the developer must keep in mind other factors, such as handling stale data, or invalidating entries when updated and so on.

*Spring Data GemFire* can [position](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/gemfire/docs/current/reference/html/#apis:spring-cache-abstraction) (also see [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/gemfire/docs/current/reference/html/#bootstrap-annotation-config-caching); preferred) Pivotal GemFire as a "caching provider" in [*Spring's Cache Abstraction*](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache), which implements the look-aside pattern using Spring's OOTB AOP framework.  For example...

```
@Service
class CustomerService {

  Autowired
  CustomerRepository customerRepository;

  @Cacheable("Customers")
  Customer findBy(Long id) {
    ...
    return customerRepository.findBy(id);
  }
}
```

In this example, the `CustomerRepository` might be backed by a RDBMS and GemFire may be the caching provider.

Of course, the CustomerService class could be making a REST API call to a remote service, a potentially expensive operation given it involves the network and the HTTP protocol.

My `caching-example` in the [Contacts Application](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application) *Reference Implementation* (RI) for SDG does just that.  It [geocodes a physical address](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/caching-example/src/main/java/example/app/service/GeocodingService.java#L59-L63) into geo-coordinates (longitude/latitude) as well as [reverse geocodes coordinates](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/caching-example/src/main/java/example/app/service/GeocodingService.java#L65-L69) back into a physical address.  The [`GeocodingRepository`](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/caching-example/src/main/java/example/app/repo/GeocodingRepository.java) ([used](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/caching-example/src/main/java/example/app/service/GeocodingService.java#L45) by the `GeocodingService`) is a [wrapper around Google's Maps API](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/caching-example/src/main/java/example/app/repo/provider/GoogleMapsApiGeocodingRepository.java) for geocoding, which makes REST API calls to Google's Maps API.

Clearly and address's geo-coordinates do not change all that frequently and are a prime candidate for caching.

On the contrary, with general data access (CRUD + Query, etc) you are using either the SDG provided [`o.s.d.g.GemfireTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/gemfire/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/GemfireTemplate.html), or better yet the [SD Repository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories) abstraction and [extension](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/gemfire/docs/current/reference/html/#_introduction) provided by SDG to access the data store as the underlying "*System of Record*" (SOR), not as a cache.  So, in this case GemFire would a suitable replacement for your database and the data access patterns have less to do with caching than they do with targeted questions about your data.  For example:

```
interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {

  List<Customer> findAllByContactEventsTimestampGreaterThanAndAddressCityIn(LocalDateTime timestamp, Collection<String> cities);

}
```

The cool thing is, using SD's Repository abstraction, I can express very simple or complex queries by following certain [conventions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/gemfire/docs/current/reference/html/#gemfire-repositories.executing-queries), for [example](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/repository-example/src/main/java/example/app/repo/gemfire/ContactRepository.java).

Anyway, caching vs. Repositories is 2 separate things and can even be combined.

Hope this helps!

-John